# Lookup values invisible on QuickEdit (JSON formatted)

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, json-formatting, quick-edit, column-formatting

I hope you can help.

SharePoint Online:

Values on a Choice column appear colour formatted on QuickEdit view.  However values in a Lookup column (values taken from a lookup list) are invisible on QuickEdit.  The values are there, but are only visible when you click into the cell.  Both Choice & Lookup columns have the same formatting.

The screenshot below shows how the columns display in regular list view versus QuickEdit view.

Can anyone help please?  Thanks.

[image: List view formatting comparisons]

Comment: Please post your JSON so we can troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON for the Lookup column, you need to reference the `.lookupValue` property.  For example:

```
"txtContent": "[$yourlookupfield.lookupValue]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply willman.  Yes - I have that in there.

To confirm, the values are there in QuickEdit view, but the formatting is making them invisible until you select them.