# SharePoint Online - JSON formatted Lookup Column - Values not visible when click to edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, modern-experience, json-formatting

Issue Description:

- I use JSON to format a lookup column in a SharePoint Online list.
- I click 'Edit in Grid View'.
- The column value and formatting are appropriately displayed in grid view.
- UNTIL I try to change a value in that column!
- When I click the field to edit it, neither the current value or the lookup values are visible.
- If I blindly click one of the invisible values on the lookup list, and then click another row, the new value does appear in the field I just left - so the functionality is not affected - just how the data is displayed (or in this case, not displayed).
- Does not impact ability to edit single items in the edit form.

Other things I've tried:  I've tried using a number of different JSON formats, including nothing more than font-weight bold (no table display-type) - and it doesn't seem to matter.  The behavior is the same. The formatting is applied until I click in the field to edit it, and then the values all become invisible.

I've spent over an hour Googling, and only came up with one thing:  Albini's Cat posted a [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277193/lookup-values-invisible-on-quickedit-json-formatted) a year or so ago, but doesn't appear to have received an answer.

Help, anyone?  Thanks!

[image: Issue Illustrated]

Here's my current JSON:

[image: Current JSON Column formatting for the above]

And another example - same issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see the exact same behavior in our SharePoint tenant:

[image]

I have used basic JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.lookupValue"
}
```

---

This seems like issue from Microsoft end. Requesting you to create a new issue/bug on [PnP List formatting repository on GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/issues). This is maintained by Microsoft employees as well as community contributors.

Also, you can raise a support ticket with Microsoft, check [Get Online support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support).