# SharePoint online column formatting seems to affect Edit In Grid view

Tags: list-view, column, json-formatting, column-formatting

Even the most basic JSON column formatter seems to make the Edit in Grid view search results list box render blank. I've tried using `@currentField.lookupValue` as well as much more complicated formatters. The search box works and results actually return judging by the "onhover" effect in the list box. I can see lookup IDs but the values are blank.

JSON formatter:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$HG_x0020_Test.lookupValue]",
  "debugMode": true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can see the exact same behavior in our SharePoint tenant:

[image]

I have used basic JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.lookupValue"
}
```

---

This seems like issue from Microsoft end. Requesting you to create a new issue/bug on [PnP List formatting repository on GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/issues). This is maintained by Microsoft employees as well as community contributors.

Also, you can raise a support ticket with Microsoft, check [Get Online support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support).

---

**Similar thread**: [SharePoint Online - JSON formatted Lookup Column - Values not visible when click to edit](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300783/sharepoint-online-json-formatted-lookup-column-values-not-visible-when-click/300791#300791)